# calling method from parent of child

Tags: lightning-web-components

Not able to show/hide the condition in child comp from parent comp when calling.

```javascript
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
export default class ParentComp extends LightningElement {
    startCounter=0;
    handleStartChange(event){
        this.startCounter = parseInt(event.target.value);
    }
    handleMaximizeCounter(){
        // const updateCounter = this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp');
        // updateCounter.addToCounter();
        //!we can use this also
        this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp').addToCounter();
        console.log('66');
    }
    handleShowHide(){
        console.log('25');
        this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp').showChildCompDetails();
        console.log('22');
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title ='Parent LWC'>
        <lightning-input class= "slds-var-m-around_small" 
                         label="Set Counter" 
                         type="number"
                         min="0" max="10000000" 
                         value={startCounter} 
                         onchange={handleStartChange}>                    
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-button class = "slds-var-m-around_small"
                          label ="Show Child Comp"
                          onclick={handleShowHide}>
        </lightning-button>
        <lightning-button class = "slds-var-m-around_small"
                          label ="ADD 100 TO COUNTER"
                          onclick={handleMaximizeCounter}>
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
    <!--  calling child comp -->
    <c-child-comp
        counter={startCounter}
    ></c-child-comp>
</template>
```

```javascript
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";
export default class childComp extends LightningElement {
    @api counter=0;
    @api areDetailsVisible=false;
    @api addToCounter(){
        this.counter +=100;
    }

    showChildCompDetails(){
        console.log('12 c',this.areDetailsVisible);
        this.areDetailsVisible=true;
    }
}
```

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Child Comp">
        <template if:true={areDetailsVisible}>
            <p class="slds-var-m-around_small">Counter Value : {counter}</p>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Comment: Why not simply ensure the parent renders the child in the required conditions, via a `template:if` on the child element itself? You should try to use standard mechanisms where possible and avoid tightly coupling your components in the JavaScript. Put as much of this coupling in the template as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the child component methods, they should be exposed. That can be done by adding the **@api** decorator to them (in your particular scenario, `showChildCompDetails()` and `addToCounter()` should be exposed).

You can check additional information [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_javascript_methods).